# Why upvote on a (likely) duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

There are several close variations of a question in [SO about merging dataframes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44768745/concatenate-data-frames-with-different-lengths), if not exact duplicates. Two of the comments point to potential duplicates. Yet the question has been voted up 3 times. I don't know why this question is voted up. The answers are good answers, but don't upvotes on the question mean that the question is original and has good application?

Comment: The duplicate might still be easier to find and thus more helpful.

Comment: @Xufox shouldn't the "original" question then be edited to make it easier to find? Maybe add an "original" tag?

Comment: because people upvote garbage all day every day. Why not dupes too?

Comment: I was going to upvote this question but then I considered looking for a duplicate, instead.  (Just kidding. )‎

Answer (score 14):

If you want to find meaning in upvotes (which is usually an exercise in futility), then the only meaning that *can* be reasonably assumed is that the upvoter thought the post fit one or more of the following criteria:

> This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear

Beyond that, break out your mind-reading device.

Answer (score 10):

I have frequently upvoted duplicate questions, because through them I have found the answer I was looking for: duplicates can very meaningfully broaden the "search funnel", meaning that more and different search terms lead to the relevant answer.